# How to self-verify an account's privileges in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I try to verify the correctness of a database configuration. So i use the account info provided in the configuration to connect to MySQL server and try to execute some queries. The problem is what queries should i issue? One possible way is to get table info from information_schema.tables and do a trivial delete/update e.g.

```
delete from some_table where 1=0 limit 1;
```

But what if the database contains no table yet?

any other methods to go through this? or another way to verify the correctness of the database configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to verify your privileges, you can run `SHOW GRANTS` and it'll show you the form of the `GRANT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Privilege information is stored in several tables in the `mysql` database. For instance, `mysql.tables_priv` contains table-level privileges, and `mysql.db` contains database-level privileges. More details can be found in the MySQL [Grants Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant-tables.html) documentation. You can query these tables to verify that the required grants have been given.

Comment: No i can not, the accounts in the configuration are for per app usage and there are definitely not granted with the privileges to access those privilege tables.

Comment: I thought you were trying to check the configuration of all accounts, not just the account running the checks.